# Draw markers on leaflet map from geojson data

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

How to import geoJson data (with more than 2000 coordinates) into leaflet map? 
This is short sample of geo json

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 44.8242557024,20.4048512901 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 44.8242557024,20.4048512901 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    }
  },...]
```

Code I've tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    html, body, #cmap {
      height: 100%;
    }

  </style>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cmap"></div>
  <script>
  var cupcakeTiles = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.emerald/page.html?access_token=cj5h2mqa63sc92srx3bu62e2j', {
    maxZoom: 18
  });

  $.getJSON("convertcsv.geojson", function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);cj5h2mqa63sc92srx3bu62e2j
      }
    });

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [44, 20],
    zoom: 7
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {       
    id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
}).addTo(map);

new L.GeoJSON(meta1nJson).addTo(map);
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens, it is just a gray background. I'm not sure where the mistake is (maybe there is more than one), but probably there is a mistake with importing geojson data and map token. 
I'm total beginner at this. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have to have many issues in your code. Firstly an element with id 'map' does not exist in your html, so the map layer cannot be placed. You have to add 'cmap' as the id in the below code.

```
var map = L.map('cmap', {
   center: [44, 20],
   zoom: 7
});
```

Also meta1nJson does not seem to be defined in your code, so the below code would not work.

```
new L.GeoJSON(meta1nJson).addTo(map);
```

The layer **cupcakeTiles** seems to be defined but is never added to the map. You also have a stray string in the below code which should be removed.

```
 $.getJSON("convertcsv.geojson", function(data) {
var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name); //cj5h2mqa63sc92srx3bu62e2j
  }
});
```